# How to add page pagination on custom wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom template that shows posts of a certain category. When I add the_posts_pagination() function in the bottom of my page, it does not generate any pagination links. What is wrong with my code?

I am new with WordPress and have little knowledge of php, so i do not know how to trace why the code does not work.

```
<?php
      global $wp_query;
      $original_page_id = get_the_ID();
      ?>
           <article <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
           <section class="page-content">
           <?php        
           $args = array ('category_name' => 'insights', 'tag' => 'for_business', 'paged' => ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1
                            );
                            $catPost = get_posts($args); 
                               foreach ($catPost as $post) : setup_postdata($post->post_excerpt); ?>
                                <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' ); ?>
                           
                                <p style="font-size: 12px"><?php the_time('j F Y'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></p>
                                <div style="color: black"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                            
                                <?php  endforeach;
                                
                                the_posts_pagination(
                                    array(
                                        'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page', 'a2b' ),
                                        'next_text'          => __( 'Next page', 'a2b' ),
                                        'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'a2b' ) . ' </span>',
                                    )
                                );
                                ?>
                            </section>
                        </article>
```

UPD I changed the code as you suggested:

```
<?php       
    global $paged;
    $paged = max( $paged. 1 );
    $query = new WP_Query (
        [
        'category_name' => 'insights',
        'tag' => 'for_business',
        'paged' => $paged,
        ]
    );
                
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        foreach ( $query->posts as $post ) { ?>
        <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' ); ?>
                            
        <p style="font-size: 12px"><?php the_time('j F Y'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></p>
        <div style="color: black"><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <?php
                    }
                }
        $per_page = 10;
        $total    = ceil( $query->found_posts / $paged );
        echo paginate_links(
            [
               'total'   => 1,
                'current' => $paged,
            ]
        );
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `the_posts_pagination()` works only with main loop (global $wp_query) WordPress. You are using your own request (`get_posts`). So you can use the `paginate_links()` for it.

```
global $paged;
$paged    = max( $paged, 1 );
$per_page = 10;
$query.   = new WP_Query(
    [
        'category_name'  => 'insights',
        'tag'            => 'for_business',
        'paged'          => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
    ]
);

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    foreach ( $query->posts as $post ) {
        // ...
    }
}
$total    = ceil( $query->found_posts / $paged );
echo paginate_links(
    [
        'total'   => 1,
        'current' => $paged,
    ]
);
```

Comment: Hi, WP Punk! Thank you for the reply. I have changed the code (see UPD), but it does not show the pagination. In addition, it does not show now automatically generated excerpts. What have I done wrong with the code?

Comment: yep, of course don't forget about 'posts_per_page' inside WP_Query

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't the [paginate_links](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/) suffice?

I've got something similar (list of custom posts, which can also be filtered based on the category):

```
$tax_slug = get_query_var( 'portfolio_type' );
// Arguments which can either have a tax_query, or just the "regular" query arguments.
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
];

// When I'm showing the pagination
if ( $show_pagination) {
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $args['paged'] = $paged;
}

// If a taxonomy was clicked, I store and add it to the $args array
if ( ! empty( $tax_slug ) ) {
    $args['tax_query'] = [[
        'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_type',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $tax_slug,
    ]];
}

// Run WP_Query()
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

echo paginate_links( array(
 'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
 'total'        => $query->max_num_pages, // WP_Query returns the max
 'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
 'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
 'show_all'     => true,
 'type'         => 'plain',
 'end_size'     => 2,
 'mid_size'     => 1,
 'prev_next'    => true,
 'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<span class="arrow" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></span> %1$s', __( 'Vorige Projecten', 'km-default' ) ),
 'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <span class="arrow" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></span>', __( 'Volgende Projecten', 'km-default' ) ),
 'add_args'     => false,
 'add_fragment' => '',
) );
```